# 3d layer slider Wordpress plugin: edit 3d colors

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a slider at the bottom of this page:

http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/williamsmurrayhamm/designvertising/

It flips but with a grey "thickness". I ideally would like to remove this thickness to make it flip thin like a sheet of paper or at least change the color to the background black. There is a Javascript file, but it has content which is incomprehensible to me:

```
 eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('23 26={1W:[{j:"13 M E",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"1e",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"13 M r",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"1e",b:F,h:"E"}},{j:"13 M N",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"1e",b:F,h:"K"}},{j:"13 M K",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"1e",b:F,h:"N"}},{j:"20",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"1e",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"Z R n",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1j,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"Z R B",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1j,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"Z R 1k-n",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1j,i:"1k-n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"Z R 1k-B",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1j,i:"1k-B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"Z R (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1j,i:"k"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:F,h:"r"}},{j:"1x 1G M E",d:1,g:1r,f:{e:25,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"22",b:T,h:"r"}},{j:"1x 1G M r",d:1,g:1r,f:{e:25,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"v",b:T,h:"r"}},{j:"1x 1G M N",d:1r,g:1,f:{e:25,i:"1k-B"},c:{o:"14",a:"v",b:T,h:"r"}},{j:"1x 1G M K",d:1r,g:1,f:{e:25,i:"1k-n"},c:{o:"14",a:"v",b:T,h:"r"}},{j:"1x Y M E",d:1,g:25,f:{e:1j,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:1g,h:"r"}},{j:"1x Y M r",d:1,g:25,f:{e:1j,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:1g,h:"E"}},{j:"1x 1U M N",d:25,g:1,f:{e:1j,i:"1k-B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:1g,h:"K"}},{j:"1x Y M K",d:25,g:1,f:{e:1j,i:"1k-n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:1g,h:"N"}},{j:"13 R m E (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:1l,h:"E"}},{j:"13 R m r (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:1l,h:"r"}},{j:"13 R m N (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:1l,h:"N"}},{j:"13 R m K (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:1l,h:"K"}},{j:"13 k R m k 1P",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:1l,h:"k"}},{j:"13 d m E (n)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"13 d m E (B)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"13 d m E (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"13 d m r (n)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"13 d m r (B)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"13 d m r (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"13 d M K m N (n)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"13 d M K m N (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"13 d M N m K (B)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"13 d M N m K (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"13 O m N (n)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"13 O m N (B)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"13 O m N (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"13 O m K (n)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"13 O m K (B)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"13 O m K (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"13 O M r m E (n)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"13 O M r m E (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"13 O M E m r (B)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"B"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"13 O M E m r (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"Z u Y R m E (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"E"}},{j:"Z u Y R m r (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"r"}},{j:"Z u Y R m N (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"N"}},{j:"Z u Y R m K (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"K"}},{j:"Z u Y k R m k 1P",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"k"}},{j:"Z u Y R M K-r (n)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"1Y"}},{j:"Z u Y R M N-E (B)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"24"}},{j:"Z u Y R M K-E (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"1T"}},{j:"Z u Y R M N-r (k)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:1f,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:1l,h:"1X"}},{j:"Z u Y d m E (n)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"Z u Y d m E (B)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"Z u Y d m E (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"Z u Y d m r (n)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"Z u Y d m r (B)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"Z u Y d m r (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"Z u Y d M K m N (n)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"Z u Y d M K m N (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"Z u Y d M N m K (B)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"Z u Y d M N m K (k)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:1a,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"Z u Y O m N (n)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"Z u Y O m N (B)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"Z u Y O m N (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"N"}},{j:"Z u Y O m K (n)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"Z u Y O m K (B)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"Z u Y O m K (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"K"}},{j:"Z u Y O M r m E (n)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"Z u Y O M r m E (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"E"}},{j:"Z u Y O M E m r (B)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"B"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"Z u Y O M E m r (k)",d:1,g:[12,16],f:{e:q,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"v",b:p,h:"r"}},{j:"1t",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"r",1h:.5}},{j:"1t d",d:4,g:1,f:{e:1f,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"r",1h:.5}},{j:"1t g",d:1,g:4,f:{e:1f,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"r",1h:.5}},{j:"1t R A",d:3,g:4,f:{e:1r,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"r",1h:.5,y:w}},{j:"1t R G",d:3,g:4,f:{e:1r,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"K",1h:.5,x:-w}},{j:"1t-1H R A",d:3,g:4,f:{e:15,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"r",1h:.5,y:w}},{j:"1t-1H R G",d:3,g:4,f:{e:15,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"K",1h:.5,x:-w}},{j:"1t 1H d",d:4,g:1,f:{e:1f,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"E",1h:.5}},{j:"1t 1H g",d:1,g:4,f:{e:1f,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"1e",b:T,h:"r",1h:.5}},{j:"1b f M r",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:T,h:"E",y:w}},{j:"1b f M E",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:-w}},{j:"1b f M K",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:T,h:"N",x:-w}},{j:"1b f M N",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"z",b:T,h:"K",x:w}},{j:"1b R M r",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:w}},{j:"1b R M E",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:-w}},{j:"1b R M K",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",x:-w}},{j:"1b R M N",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",x:w}},{j:"1b d M K",d:[6,12],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",x:w}},{j:"1b d M N",d:[6,12],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",x:-w}},{j:"1b g M r",d:1,g:[6,12],f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:-w}},{j:"1b g M E",d:1,g:[6,12],f:{e:19,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:w}},{j:"1u d M r",d:[3,10],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:w}},{j:"1u d M E",d:[3,10],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",y:-w}},{j:"1u g M K",d:1,g:[3,10],f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",x:-w}},{j:"1u g M N",d:1,g:[3,10],f:{e:19,i:"B"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",x:w}},{j:"1u u 1z f M r",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"E",1h:.1,1y:-w,y:w}},{j:"1u u 1z f M E",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:.1,1y:w,y:-w}},{j:"1u u 1z R M r",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"E",1y:-1v}},{j:"1u u 1z R M E",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1y:-1v}},{j:"1u u 1z R M k",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:19,i:"k"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"k",1y:-1v}},{j:"D f 1M",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:.1}},{j:"D f M 1L",d:1,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:2}},{j:"D R k",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:1r,i:"k"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:.1}},{j:"D R M 1L k",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:1r,i:"k"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:2}},{j:"D 1M u 1z R k",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:1r,i:"k"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:.1,1y:w}},{j:"D u 1z R M 1L k",d:[3,4],g:[3,4],f:{e:1r,i:"k"},c:{o:"14",a:"z",b:T,h:"r",1h:2,1y:-w}},{j:"1B-Y R 21",d:3,g:4,f:{e:15,i:"n"},c:{o:"X",a:"v",b:1Z,h:"1T"}},{j:"1B-Y d A",d:6,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"r"}},{j:"1B-Y d G",d:6,g:1,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"K"}},{j:"1B-Y g A",d:1,g:8,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"r"}},{j:"1B-Y g G",d:1,g:8,f:{e:0,i:"n"},c:{o:"Q",a:"z",b:T,h:"K"}}],1V:[{j:"1c f m E (l&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:1E},a:"1K",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{y:l},a:"z",b:F,h:"A"}},{j:"1c f m r (l&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:-1E},a:"1K",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{y:-l},a:"z",b:F,h:"A"}},{j:"1c f m N (l&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:-1E},a:"1K",b:1w,h:"G"},C:{c:{x:-l},a:"z",b:1w,h:"G"}},{j:"1c f m K (l&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:1E},a:"1K",b:1w,h:"G"},C:{c:{x:l},a:"z",b:1w,h:"G"}},{j:"1c R m E (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:F,h:"A"}},{j:"1c R m r (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"B"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"v",b:F,h:"A"}},{j:"1c R m N (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-n"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1c R m K (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-B"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1D S R k (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1I,h:"A"}},{j:"1C S R k (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:1I,h:"G"}},{j:"D u S R m E (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.1A},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S R m r (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.1A},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S R m N (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-n"},L:{c:{I:.1A},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S R m K (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-B"},L:{c:{I:.1A},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u A S R k (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.1A,x:1j},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:1I,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0},b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u G S R k (l&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.1A,y:-15},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"H",b:1I,h:"G"},C:{c:{y:0},b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"1c d m E (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1c d m r (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1c d m N (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1c d m K (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"B"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1D S d k (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1C S d k (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"G"}},{j:"1C S d k (1F&#t;)",d:[3,7],g:1,f:{e:1S,i:"k"},s:{c:{x:-1F},a:"v",b:1Q,h:"G"}},{j:"D u S d m E (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:1n,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u S d m r (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"H",b:1n,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u S d m N (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:p,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u S d m K (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:p,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u A S d k (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:1n,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u G S d k (l&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:19,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:p,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"1c O m E (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1c O m r (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1c O m N (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1c O m K (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"B"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1D S O k (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1C S O k (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"G"}},{j:"1D S O k (1F&#t;)",d:1,g:[4,9],f:{e:1S,i:"k"},s:{c:{y:1F},a:"v",b:1Q,h:"A"}},{j:"D u S O m E (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:19,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:p,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u S O m r (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:19,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"v",b:p,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u S O m N (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:19,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:1n,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u S O m K (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"H",b:1n,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u A S O k (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:p,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u G S O k (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:1n,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"1R 1N 1O u S m E (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:-1j},b:p,a:"z"},s:{c:{x:1j,y:l},a:"v",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0,e:W},a:"z",b:p}},{j:"1R 1N 1O u S m r (l&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:-1j},b:p,a:"z"},s:{c:{x:1j,y:-l},a:"v",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0,e:W},a:"z",b:p}},{j:"1b 1s m E (w&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1b 1s m r (w&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:-w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1b 1s m N (w&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"G"}},{j:"1b 1s m K (w&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"G"}},{j:"D u 17 1s m E (w&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{I:.8,x:1j,y:1v},a:"1e",b:1w,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0,y:w},b:1w,a:"1e"}},{j:"D u 17 1s m r (w&#t;)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{I:.8,x:1j,y:-1v},a:"1e",b:1w,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0,y:-w},b:1w,a:"1e"}},{j:"D u 17 1o m E (w&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u 17 1o m r (w&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u 17 1o m N (w&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u 17 1o m K (w&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u A 17 1o k (w&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.1i,x:-15},b:1p,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:q},a:"H",b:1p,h:"A"},C:{c:{y:w,x:0},b:1p,a:"H"}},{j:"D u G 17 1o k (w&#t;)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.1i,y:15},b:1p,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:q},a:"H",b:1p,h:"G"},C:{c:{x:w,y:0},b:1p,a:"H"}},{j:"1b d m E (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1b d m r (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{y:-w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1D 17 d k (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"D u 17 d m E (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:3},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W,x:0},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u 17 d m r (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:3},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W,x:0},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u 17 d m N (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u 17 d m K (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u A 17 d k (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:3},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W,x:0},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u G 17 d k (w&#t;)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u A 17 1J d m E (w&#t;)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{I:.P,x:5,y:1v},a:"18",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0,y:w},a:"18",b:F}},{j:"D u A 17 1J d m r (w&#t;)",d:[7,11],g:1,f:{e:q,i:"B"},s:{c:{I:.P,x:5,y:-1v},a:"18",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{x:0,y:-w},a:"18",b:F}},{j:"1b O m N (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1b O m K (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"B"},s:{c:{x:w},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"1C 17 O k (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[5,9],f:{e:q,i:"k"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"v",b:F,h:"G"}},{j:"D u 17 O m N (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u 17 O m K (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u 17 O m E (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"n"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u 17 O m r (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"B"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u A 17 O k (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:w},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u G 17 O k (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"k"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-w},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"J",b:p}},{j:"D u G 17 1J O m E (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"n"},s:{c:{I:.P,x:1v,y:-5},a:"18",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{x:w,y:0},a:"18",b:F}},{j:"D u G 17 1J O m r (w&#t;)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:q,i:"B"},s:{c:{I:.P,x:-1v,y:-5},a:"18",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{x:-w,y:0},a:"18",b:F}},{j:"1c 1s m E (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n",V:"U"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1c 1s m r (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n",V:"U"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"A"}},{j:"1c 1s m N (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n",V:"U"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"G"}},{j:"1c 1s m K (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:1,f:{e:q,i:"n",V:"U"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:1d,h:"G"}},{j:"D u S 1o m E (l&#t;, U V)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"n",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S 1o m r (l&#t;, U V)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"B",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S 1o m N (l&#t;, U V)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-n",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S 1o m K (l&#t;, U V)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"1k-B",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:1m,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{b:1g,a:"H"}},{j:"D u A S 1o k (l&#t;, U V)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.1i},b:1p,a:"18"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:1p,h:"A"},C:{b:1p,a:"H"}},{j:"D u G S 1o k (l&#t;, U V)",d:[2,4],g:[4,7],f:{e:q,i:"k",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.1i},b:1p,a:"18"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"H",b:1p,h:"G"},C:{b:1p,a:"H"}},{j:"D u S d m E (l&#t;, U V)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:1i,i:"n",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:3},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1n,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W,x:0},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S d m r (l&#t;, U V)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:1i,i:"B",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:3},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"v",b:1n,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W,x:0},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S d m N (l&#t;, U V)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:1i,i:"n",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S d m K (l&#t;, U V)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:1i,i:"B",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u A S d k (l&#t;, U V)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:1i,i:"k",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P,x:3},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"v",b:1n,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W,x:0},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u G S d k (l&#t;, U V)",d:[5,9],g:1,f:{e:1i,i:"k",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S O m N (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:1i,i:"n",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:1n,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S O m K (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:1i,i:"B",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:l},a:"v",b:1n,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S O m E (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:1i,i:"n",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u S O m r (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:1i,i:"B",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:-l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u A S O k (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:1i,i:"k",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{y:l},a:"H",b:F,h:"A"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}},{j:"D u G S O k (l&#t;, U V)",d:1,g:[7,11],f:{e:1i,i:"k",V:"U"},L:{c:{I:.P},b:p,a:"J"},s:{c:{x:-l},a:"v",b:1n,h:"G"},C:{c:{e:W},a:"z",b:1q}}]}',62,131,'||||||||||easing|duration|transition|rows|delay|tile|cols|direction|sequence|name|random|180|to|forward|type|600|75|left|animation|176|and|easeInOutQuart|90|rotateX|rotateY|easeOutQuart|horizontal|reverse|after|Scaling|right|1e3|vertical|easeInOutBack|scale3d|easeOutBack|top|before|from|bottom|columns|85|mixed|tiles|spinning|750|large|depth|200|slide|sliding|Fading||||Sliding|fade|||turning|easeInOutQuint|55|100|Turning|Spinning|1500|easeInOutQuad|50|350|scale|65|30|col|500|450|1200|cuboids|700|400|35|cuboid|Carousel|Flying|45|800|Smooth|rotate|rotating|95|Mirror|Vertical|Horizontal|91|540|fading|mirror|1300|drunk|easeInQuart|out|in|colums|scaling|directions|2e3|Drunk|150|topright|sliging|t3d|t2d|bottomleft|topleft|850|Crossfading|diagonal|linear|var|bottomright||layerSliderTransitions'.split('|')))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was a simple css tweak in layerslider.css.